# "git show HEAD" results in "fatal : ambiguous 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree"

Tags: git

I'm trying to fix a problem with `git`.

When I enter `git show HEAD`, I got the error `fatal : ambiguous 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`.

What could I do to fix this problem?

The display of `git status` is :

```
git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   script.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    script.txt~
```

Comment: what is the output of `git status`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `HEAD` because you have not yet made any commits to the repository.  `HEAD` usually points to the currently checked-out commit, but since you have no commits in your tree, `HEAD` doesn't point to anything, so `git show HEAD` fails.

Comment: This made sense in my situation too. I had a repo without a commit and I wanted to `git reset HEAD^`, but since there wasn't a previous commit, a `HEAD` wasn't created.